# Verify matrix identity

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse

The question:

> Show that if $A$, $B$, and $A+B$ are invertible matrices with the
>   same size, then: $$A(A^{-1}+B^{-1})B(A+B)^{-1} = I$$

I began by multiplying the first $A$:

$I+AB^{-1}B(A+B)^{-1}=I$

and then

$I + A(A+B)^{-1} = I$

At this point I'm not sure what to do. Should I just assume $A(A+B)^{-1} = 0$, or does that not work to prove this?

Comment: You dropped parentheses... You should have $(I+AB^{-1})B(A+B)^{-1}$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{eqnarray}
A(A^{-1}+B^{-1})B(A+B)^{-1}&=&[A(A^{-1}+B^{-1})]B(A+B)^{-1}=(AA^{-1}+AB^{-1})B(A+B)^{-1}\\
&=&[(I+AB^{-1})B](A+B)^{-1}=(B+AB^{-1}B)(A+B)^{-1}\\
&=&(B+A)(A+B)^{-1}=(A+B)(A+B)^{-1}=I.
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 0):

You are wrong when you multiplied by the first $A$, note 
$$
A(A^{-1}+B^{-1})B = (I+AB^{-1})B =(B+AI)= (B+A)
$$
Then of course $(B+A)(A+B)^{-1}=I$.

Answer (score 0):

Multiply both sides by $A+B$: you will get $A(A^{-1}+B^{-1})B=A+B$ but the left hand side is $AA^{-1}B+AB^{-1}B=B+A$ as desired.